# Instantiate STI inherited-model results from exec_query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Given this query that returns a hash:

```
def query
  sql = %(SELECT * FROM components
          INNER JOIN brands_components ON brands_components.component_id = components.id
          INNER JOIN brands ON brands.id = brands_components.brand_id
          INNER JOIN components_templates ON components.id = components_templates.component_id
          WHERE components_templates.template_id = #{@template.id}
          AND (components.user_id IS null OR components.user_id = #{@user.id})
          AND brands.id = #{@user.brand_id})
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
end
```

How can I instantiate the result to an ActiveRecord collection (especially if they represent different models [i.e., STI-inherited from `Component`])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the sql to [find_by_sql](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql) will instantiate the models so changing the method to

```
def query
  sql = [some sql]
  Component.find_by_sql(sql)
end
```

should give you what you want. It will also instantiate the correct subclass for every record.

Comment: The docs here though say that "if you call a complicated SQL query which spans multiple tables the columns specified by the SELECT will be attributes of the model, whether or not they are columns of the corresponding table." This seems to ignore subclasses if the statement is changed to `SELECT components.*` to prevent noise from the join tables.